# Can someone help me with this?

Tags: backbone.js

I have following model in my backbone.js-

```
var Book = Backbone.Model.extend({

    defaults: {
        id: 0,
        title: 'Book',
        price: 100,
        quantity: 0
    }  

});
```

with collection as,

```
var BookList = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: Book,

    url: function () {
        return 'Handler.ashx'            
    }

});
```

By using collection.fetch() method in this backbone,I can fetch book list from database using following handler.ashx

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="VB" Class="Handler" %>

Imports System
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient


Public Class Handler : Implements IHttpHandler

    Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
            Dim detail As List(Of MyBookList) = GetBookDetail()

            If detail.Count > 0 Then
                context.Response.ContentType = "application/json"
                Dim json As String = New JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(detail)
                context.Response.Write(json)
            Else
                context.Response.StatusCode = 404
           End If
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
        Get
            Return False
        End Get
    End Property

    Protected Function GetBookDetail() As List(Of MyBookList)

        Dim ConnectionString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("con").ConnectionString
        Dim sqlConn As New MySqlConnection(ConnectionString)
        Dim sqlCommand As New MySqlCommand
        sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConn
        Dim dReader As MySqlDataReader
        Dim dtExcelRecords As New DataTable()
        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        sqlConn.Open()

        sqlCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM booklist "
        sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        dReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader()

        Dim book As New List(Of MyBookList)

        If dReader.HasRows Then
            While dReader.Read()
                Dim bookObject As New MyBookList
                bookObject.title = dReader(0)
                bookObject.price = dReader(1)
                bookObject.id = dReader(2)
                bookObject.quantity = dReader(3)
                book.Add(bookObject)
            End While
        End If

        Return book
    End Function
End Class
```

I want to know what code should be added to backbone.js and handler to update particular model in booklist collection.I have following save method trigered when save button is clicked..

```
updateBookTitle: function () {
        var a = $('.title').val();
        this.model.set({ title: a });
        this.model.save();        
    },
```

how the handler url should be modified to post model Id while saving?

Comment: You can't save a model through a collection but through the model itself. Did you try adding urlRoot to your model? See also http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save

Comment: Is it necessary to use a function to return the collection URL? It's just returning a string? The model will default to using the collection's URL plus the model ID.

Comment: I have seen save method,after calling save put request will be sent to server with models ID appended to url and it's attributes,I want to know how to retrieve that attributes in my handler to update the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backbone is intended to work with RESTful services, which WebForms are not. With .NET you should really consider using the WebAPI or MVC frameworks. If you *must* use a webform, you'll need to either modify how Backbone's `sync` works, or you'll have to manually code up in your .aspx the action based on the Request's HTTP Method: `GET`=List, `POST`=Save, `PUT`=Update, `DELETE`=Delete.

Comment: Thanks for your response Chris.I want to use webform,I also thought of modifying Backbones SYNC method,but i am not getting what should be modified in that.